# A connection to the notebook server could not be established. gpu2

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, gpu

i'm trying to run my codes on the gpu using jupyter. i followeed the instructions on  [this link](https://www.techentice.com/how-to-make-jupyter-notebook-to-run-on-gpu/). it went well until i tried to open a notebook using the gpu2 as the kernel. i keep getting a connection failed message as shown in the image. how to solve this problem? [image: error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**

in my case IO had to open the anaconda navigator then open the environment tab, then i selected the gpu2 env and installed the jupyter packages in it. Once that was done, it worked like a charm.